# Looking for illustrator script which will select a path by size

Tags: illustrator-scripting

I work on files which include thousands of short paths. I need to remove these short paths. Often I can not remove them by choosing the line weight or color because the file originators, use the same line weight & color throughout the very large files. Per project/file, the paths vary in size but are usually very similar in length.

I am looking for a robust script which can select paths by length/size. And do so in very large numbers.

Does anyone know of an illustrator V 25.2.1 script which has these capabilities.

Thank you in advance for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I use this script.

There are some controls to select small, big by dimension, etc.

It's very useful.

https://github.com/nvkelso/illustrator-scripts/blob/master/other-authors/jwundes/SelectPathsBySize.jsx

[image]